# How to find the range of $\theta$ where $a*\sin(\theta) + b*\cos(\theta) < l$

Tags: trigonometry

Given $a*\sin(\theta) + b*\cos(\theta) < l$, how can I find valid values for $\theta$ in the range of $0..2\pi$?

I was able to solve a similar equation using [Solving $a \sin\theta + b \cos\theta = c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2502976/solving-a-sin-theta-b-cos-theta-c), but for my actual problem I am not really sure what to do.

Comment: Where do $a$ and $b$ live? First use your previous work at solving $a \sin \theta + b\cos \theta = c$, but replace c everywhere by l.  That will establish the boundary of yourinequality.

Comment: You can write $\cos\theta$ as $\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta}$ to get a quadratic inequality in $\sin\theta$. It should be bounded between 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can say $n=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and then multiply and divide both sides, obtaining: $$\frac{a}{n}\sin(\theta)+\frac{b}{n}\cos(\theta)<l\leftrightarrow\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin(\theta)+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos(\theta)<l$$
From here, you can write: $$\sin\left(\theta+\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)\right)<l$$
Solving this is very simple, in fact: $$\arcsin(l)-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)+2k\pi<\theta<\arcsin(l)-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)+2k\pi+\pi$$